# How to create a function for configuring defined ports on a stm32f4xx platform?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

I am using **stm32f4xx** with **HAL library** and I have configured some ports like this:

```
  #define Led1 GPIO_PIN_1
  #define Led1_Port GPIOC

  #define Led2 GPIO_PIN_2
  #define Led2_PoRT GPIOE

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Led1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(Led1_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Led2;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(Led2_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

I want to move the code above (not the `define`s of course) to a function which can be then called and setup the ports in the exact same way as above:

```
  #define Led1 GPIO_PIN_1
  #define Led1_Port GPIOC

  #define Led2 GPIO_PIN_2
  #define Led2_PoRT GPIOE

  void GPIOConfig(*Pin,GPIO_TypeDef *Port)
  {
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = &Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(&Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  }

  // Calling the configuration function
  GPIOConfig(Led1,Led1_Port);
  GPIOConfig(Led2,Led2_Port);
```

For some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Please can you try and re-word / explain the question better as it does not really make sense.

Comment: Okay. İt is fixed. I want to create a function, and I want to use defined port and pins with the function

Comment: Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your init function should be more like this as Pin is just a number and not a pointer. Also you are also passing Port in as a pointer which is what you want to pass to HAL_GPIO_Init (and not the address of the pointer):

```
void GPIOConfig(uint32_t Pin,GPIO_TypeDef *Port)
{
   GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Pin;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
   HAL_GPIO_Init(Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
```

And then should called like:

```
GPIOConfig( Led1, Led1_Port );
```